# Join string containg quotation marks

Tags: python, html, join, tags

How can i join a string that contains quotation marks? Here is an example, of a program to generate HTML image tags. But the program is not printing correctly.

```
import sys

sys.stdout = open("/Users/kyle/images.html", "w")
for x in xrange(100,490):
    site = "http://www.example.com/image"+str(x)+".jpg"
    print "<img src=""+site+"">"
```

It will print properly this way `print "<img src="+'"'+site+'"'+">"` 
But i want to know if there is another way that is more simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use a single-quoted string for the `print` statement, and then include the double-quoted strings literally:

```
print '<img src="' + site + '">'
```

I generally prefer using `str.format()` for this kind of thing, though, because it makes the position of the output more obvious.

```
print '<img src="{0}">'.format(site)
```

However, if you're generating large amounts of HTML, you might be better off using a templating language like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/), which will handle auto-escaping and whatnot better.

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't care which quotes you use.

```
print '<img src="' + site + '">'
```

Answer (score 1):

Others already showed `.format` which is very cool. Another way can be:

```
print "<img src='%s'>" % site
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also always escape the inner quote characters:

```
    print "<img src=\""+site+"\">"
```